# Codeigniter `No Input File Specified` & `404 Page Not Found` Errors when Live

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have a [website I built on codeiginiter 2.0.1](http://justanil.co.uk) (My own personal site). I built this application locally using WAMP and it works 100% as it should (Locally). I uploaded this to my live server and I keep getting "404 page not found" error. This error is coming from codeigniter through my Home->Error method, not the server, so code igniter is definitely working.

Here is my routes config. If I change the 404_override to 'Home'. It loads my home controller as it should, but when I go to ANY page I get the 404 page not found.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = 'Home/Error';
```

I suspect this may have something to do with my .htaccess & Codeigniter config.

```
// Codeigniter Config.php - Note: My Hosting is with Godaddy. [CGI/FastCGI]
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
// Tried Auto and All others, REQUEST_URI works fastest for me.
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

I tried so many links through SO & Google to fix this, the ones I tried repetitively are below.
 - [CodeIgniter 404 Page Not Found, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752609/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-but-why)
 - [codeigniter 404 on existing controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123533/codeigniter-404-on-existing-controller)
 - http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/60469/#297477
 - http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Godaddy_Installaton_Tips
 - Amongst many others

I'm sure this has goto do with the htaccess and mod_rewrite, Any Ideas?

---

**Update**
If I change the the `$route['404_override'] = 'Home/Error'` to any of my controllers, they show and work as expected, but for some reason, its always throwing a 404 page.

If I go to: `/index.php/home` - I get the error `No input file specified.`

Comment: Make sure your host has activated url rewrite in apache.

Comment: It is by default on godaddy - http://help.godaddy.com/article/899

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem..
Make sure your controller **filenames are lowercase**.
`controllers/Home.php` Is incorrect, This was throwing the 404 page not found error.
`controllers/home.php` Is Correct.

Comment: Isn't @chrisramon gave you the answer about the lowercase first ?

Answer (score 9):

**first controllers name should be in lowercase like:**
`$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`

**then you might leave in blank the index_page:**
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

**finally in .htaccess should be alongside index.php in the base path directory, you might change the last line like:**
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/index.php?$1 [L]`

hope it solve

Comment: +1 for the first one - on WAMP it's likely the server handles path names in a case-insensitive fashion.